# How to disable background view with dark transparent color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

I created animation for a uiview that slides from the bottom of the screen, but i want after the view slides on to the screen to make the bg view  disabled and with dark bg like this:

[image]

How can i do this? Also when i tap the dark transparent view i want it to slide out and to make the bg view enabled.

this is how I do the sliding animation:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        self.slidingView.hidden = NO;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        self.slidingView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,20);
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

Thanksss

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing on a recent project.
Instead of adding only one view which is the view that contains the picker, add a parent view to it.
So what you will be adding to your view controller is a view that will be the size of your screen with a transparent black background and then add to it a subview the view with your picker with your custom animation.

Another way to do this is to have a view in your view controller that is initially hidden and when you show your picker view you show it.

I can help you better if you can share your code.

Edit:

-add a view in your view controller with the same width and height, with leading, top, trailing and bottom constraints.

-have an outlet for this view (ex:backgroundView)

-in your `viewDidLoad:` add the following line:

```
self.backgroundView.hidden=YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourcodeToCloseTheView)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

-and in your `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` add this line:

```
self.backgroundView.hidden=NO;
```

Just make sure that the backgroundView is behind your pickerView in IB.

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks buddy, I edited my question and added the method that is sliding the view, its an action sheet method since sliding this view is depending on an action sheet button. what more code can I share to help you help me :)? i got what you said but it will help if you can share it with some code. im using xibs by the way

Comment: If you can share your project on github or ... that would be great

Comment: unfortunately i can't share it on github but i can share the pieces of code you need, just let me know what data are you missing :)